# MVC return Controller Action to View + #id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have publish a new website where the website.pt/contact page is now at the website.pt#contact-us - how can change my actual controller's action to reflect this change?

```
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(); -> Index#contact-us
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#contact-us` is a URL location hash and has nothing to do with a `View`. Instead, try to redirect to that specific URL hash with `return Redirect("website.pt#contact-us")`.